# Imprimir el dos variables de dos tablas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

mi problema es el siguiente: quiero imprimir el resultado de dos campos que se encuentran en dos tablas distintas y que se muestre de esta forma:

campo1-tabla1 
campo1-tabla2 
campo1-tabla1
campo1-tabla2

Lo que tengo es esto y me imprime lo valores de una tabla(campo) y luego la del otro:

```html
$connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["bl3"]);
$query = "SELECT bl FROM caso WHERE bl LIKE '%".$request."%' UNION SELECT bl FROM csuelta WHERE bl LIKE '%".$request."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
 echo  $data[] = $row["bl"];
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara.  Quiza deberias agregar como se ve ahora y como desas que se vea.

Comment: @alanfcm ahora mismo me imprime los valores de esta forma:
</br>
campo1-tabla1</br>
campo1-tabla1</br>
campo1-tabla1</br>
campo1-tabla1</br>
campo1-tabla1</br>
campo1-tabla2</br>
campo1-tabla2</br>
campo1-tabla2</br>
campo1-tabla2</br>
campo1-tabla2</br>

y quiero que me imprima asi:
campo1-tabla1</br>
campo1-tabla2</br>
campo1-tabla1</br>
campo1-tabla2</br>

Comment: @alanfcm o esto 
resultado de tabla1-campo1:
1, 3, 6, 7

Resultado de tabla2 campo1:
2, 4, 5, 8

Ressultado combinado:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Comment: Los valores del campo 1 son numericos?  Quieres que esos valores se ordenenen o que siempre se alternen tabla1, tabla2?

Comment: @alanfcm son alfanumericos (varchar), y si, que se alternen

Comment: Creo que lo que pides no es posible, por lo menos no con ese query.  Talvez la unica opcion seria hacer 2 queries separadas y luego convertirlas a arrays en php.